Having problem on showing the main content in an Administration page of a Flutter Web Application
I am developing a responsive Web Application Administration page in Flutter that uses Supabase, Riverpod and GoRouter. In my Home Page, I used a Scaffold widget with an Appbar, and created a MenuPanel that was placed in a Drawer widget. The body should contain main content which should be a Page/Screen. I am relatively new to Flutter and thinking like what I do in PHP/Javascript that there should only one declaration of the header and menu/navigation bar, while only the main section changes.  How can I do that in Flutter, what widget should I use for the main section? For example, I have an AddUser and ViewUser pages. Here are my current code (some lines are omitted):
Home Page
class HomePage extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});
  static String get routeName => 'home';

  @override
  ConsumerState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends ConsumerState<HomePage> {
  
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  
    return LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
      return Scaffold(
          key: _scaffoldKey,
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: SizedBox(
              ... ,
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    ref.read(authProvider).signOut();
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.logout))
            ],
            leading: constraints.maxWidth > 600
                ? null
                : IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      if (_scaffoldKey.currentState!.isDrawerOpen) {
                        _scaffoldKey.currentState!.openEndDrawer();
                      } else {
                        _scaffoldKey.currentState!.openDrawer();
                      }
                    },
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.menu)),
          ),
          drawer: constraints.maxWidth > 600 ? null : const MenuPanel(),
          body: constraints.maxWidth > 600
              ? Row(
                  children: [
                    const Expanded(flex: 2, child: MenuPanel()),
                    Expanded(
                        flex: 8,
                        child: SafeArea(
                       // What should I put here to show the page/widget      
                        )
                    )
                  ],
                )
              : SafeArea(
                   //Same as above. What should I put here to show the page/widget      
               );
    });
  }
}

MenuPanel
class MenuPanel extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MenuPanel({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final String userAccountType =
        ref.watch(userProvider.notifier).state!.accountType;
    final router = ref.watch(routerProvider);

    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          if (userAccountType == 'admin') ...[
            ListTile(
              title: const Text("View Users"),
              onTap: () {
                // Is this correct?
                router.go(ViewUsers.routeName);
              },
            ),
           
            ListTile(
              title: const Text("Add User"),
              onTap: () {
                // Is this correct?
                router.go(AddUser.routeName);
              },
            ),
          ] else ...[
            ListTile(
              title: const Text("Menu Item "),
              onTap: () {},
            ),
          ]
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

Router Provider
final _key = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

final routerProvider = Provider<GoRouter>((ref) {
  final authState = ref.watch(authProvider);

  return GoRouter(
      navigatorKey: _key,
      debugLogDiagnostics: false,
      initialLocation: '/',
      refreshListenable: authState,
      routes: <GoRoute>[
        ...
        GoRoute(
          path: '/',
          name: HomePage.routeName,
          builder: (context, state) {
            return const HomePage();
          },
        ),
        GoRoute(
            path: '/viewUsers',
            name: ViewUsers.routeName,
            builder: (context, state) {
              return const ViewUsers();
            }),
        GoRoute(
            path: '/addUser',
            name: AddUser.routeName,
            builder: (context, state) {
              return const AddUser();
            }),
      ],
      redirect: (context, state) {
       ...
      });
});

Add user/ dummy page
class AddUser extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const AddUser({super.key});
  static String get routeName => 'addUser';

  @override
  ConsumerState createState() => _AddUserState();
}

class _AddUserState extends ConsumerState<AddUser> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Column(
      children: [
        Text("Add User"),
        Text("Blah blah"),
      ],
    );
  }
}

I am employing the help of the free CoPilot/Bing but its answers are not being accepted and possibly deprecated.  Is there a way to just change the main section if a link in the Menu Panel is clicked or I just have to declare/return in every page/screen like in Add User and View Users pages a Scaffold widget with the same Appbar and Drawer content?

If you are using go_router then use shell route. To implement this or you use builder fn in material app if you want persistent drawer in all pages

@Ultranmus thanks, shellroute is indeed what I needed. However, I am having issues implementing it.

As Ultranmus commented, the answer for my question is by using ShellRoute. As much as I want to post the code, I have a new question/issue encountered on Duplicate Globalkey while using ShellRoute

can add your router file including the use of navigation key, this issue is normally happen with incorrect use of global keys. Point to be noted that you need 2 route keys one for shell route and one for go router.

I have posted the updated code in the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78515400/duplicate-globalkey-detected-in-the-widget-tree-issue-in-a-flutter-web-app-using . It is pointing to the 2nd Expanded widget where the section should be shown. It was inside a Row widget, where there are 2 Expanded widget, one for the Menu Panel for the links, the other is for the section that will be changed
